# Hierachy drill down for multiple charts

Tags: powerbi

I have a report with 4 graphs, each have the same category and sub category. And two of them have date as well, like so:

Axis:

```
 -Month
 --Catecory
 ---Subcatecory
```

I was wondering if it's possible to make a slicer or button that could change the view of these four graphs at the same time, as I would like to have an overall view with catecory and go deeper into the view with subcatecory. Without changing the values.

I checked the newest feature in the december 2017 update about drill down, but it requires me to click on a graph axis point and by doing so it changes the values, and only shows subcategories for that catecory.

Answer (score 0):

you can include an date slicer. check this link for reference
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/tag/date-slicer/